# How can I upload videos to JWPlayer with Java (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, jwplayer

I have a Java Spring Boot web app which should allow the users to upload their videos. I did some researches and I found that JWPlayer is the best solution in this way.

I would like to upload videos to JWPlayer and store in a database the id of the uploaded video related to a particular user.

The only problem is that the documentation is not so clear, and I don't understand how can I interact with JWPlayer with my Spring Boot back end.

There is just [this page](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/docs/developer-guide/management-api/uploading-videos/#cdn-accelerated-uploads) which does not show any code nor give any intuition of the process.

Comment: "There is just this page which does not show any code nor give any intuition of the process." I see code. I see intuition of the process. What are you looking at?

Comment: @Michael I don't see the code honestly... I don't understand the whole process... from the browser to my backend to JWPlayer... is it shown on the page? I cannot really find it. I have a spring boot web app and I would like to upload video from the browser and store them on JWPlayer, but as I said I don't know what's the best process...

Comment: `def create_video(...`

Comment: That's not the whole process... and how can I translate that code into Java? It uses the jwplatform python library which I'm not sure how to substitute in Java. And how can I reach that point? How can I pass from the browser to that function?

Comment: Use jython. If you can't figure it out, use the "regular style upload" which is just a HTTP request.

Comment: @StefanoSambruna take a look at https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/reference/v1/uploads.html for more information re how to make the API calls yourself. We're looking at revamping our developer docs with example code in the next month or two.

Answer (score 0):

JWPlayer doesn't provide a Java or Spring Boot integration, but it does have APIs that you can call from Java. The steps go as follows:

- Create your video metadata by calling [`/v1/videos/create`](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/reference/v1/methods/videos/create.html). I highly recommend using the S3 upload method. If you're not sure how to make this call you can read about the [call structure](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/reference/v1/call_syntax.html) and [authentication](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/reference/v1/authentication.html)
- Upload your video by using the `link` returned in the create call. You can read more about how to do this [here](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/reference/v1/s3_uploads.html) if you do the S3 method, or [here](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/reference/v1/uploads.html) otherwise.
- There is a pretty good example of how this entire process goes written in Python [on the page](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/docs/developer-guide/management-api/uploading-videos/#cdn-accelerated-uploads) you linked.
- If you're uploading videos on behalf of your users, it'd probably be easiest to do this on the frontend with JavaScript instead of proxying through your Java application

Comment: Ok I'm using s3 but I'm having some problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697391/jwplayer-and-s3-calculated-signature-does-not-match-the-provided-one