# JWPlayer and S3: calculated signature does not match the provided one

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-s3, jwplayer

I'm trying to upload videos to JWPlayer using AWS S3.

My backend is coded in Spring so I'm using Java. I manage to request the upload URL but every time I try to submit a POST request with it I get back a "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error from AWS.

Without s3 it works just fine... The documentation is not that clear in this sense... There isn't a well done example from the beginning to the end, I mean, an example with the whole process: authentication, url request and upload of the video. So I'm struggling trying to understand what's the problem here.

With this method I get the update url.

```
public String createVideo(String title, String description, String username) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        String nonce = generateNonce(8);
        String timestamp = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
        params.put("api_format", "json");
        params.put("author", username);
        params.put("title", title);
        params.put("description", description);
        params.put("upload_method", "s3");
        params.put("api_key", jwPlayerConfig.getKey());
        params.put("api_nonce", nonce);
        params.put("api_timestamp", timestamp);
        params.put("api_signature", generateAPISignature(params, jwPlayerConfig.getSecret()));
        String urlParameters = getParamsString(params);
        String response = requestAuthenticationToken(jwPlayerConfig.getUrl() + jwPlayerConfig.getCreateVideoUrl(), urlParameters);
        JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        System.out.println(myObject);
        JSONObject link = myObject.getJSONObject("link");
        return "https://" + link.getString("address") + link.getString("path") +
                "?api_format=json" +
                "&redirect_address=" + jwPlayerConfig.getCreateVideoRedirectAddress() +
                "&key_in_path=True" +
                "&AWSAccessKeyId=" + link.getJSONObject("query").getString("AWSAccessKeyId") +
                "&Expires=" + link.getJSONObject("query").get("Expires").toString() +
                "&Signature=" + link.getJSONObject("query").getString("Signature");
    }
```

This method is called by a controller method of Spring and it uses these other methods in order to generate the upload url:

```
public String generateAPISignature(Map<String, String> params, String api_secret){
        final Map<String, String> sorted = params.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
        StringBuilder concat = new StringBuilder();
        for(String key: sorted.keySet()){
            concat.append(key);
            concat.append("=");
            concat.append(sorted.get(key));
            concat.append("&");
        }
        concat.delete(concat.length() - 1, concat.length());
        concat.append(api_secret);
        return DigestUtils.sha1Hex(concat.toString());
    }
```

This method generates a nonce:

```
public static String generateNonce(int length){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        StringBuilder nonce = new StringBuilder();
        do{
            nonce.append(rnd.nextInt(10));
        }while(nonce.length() < length);
        return nonce.toString();
    }
```

And this other one builds the parameters string from the parameters Map:

```
public String getParamsString(Map<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("&");
        }

        String resultString = result.toString();

        return resultString.length() > 0
                ? resultString.substring(0, resultString.length() - 1)
                : resultString;
    }
```

The html form looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="url">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
    <button type="submit">Upload video</button>
</form>
```

The error message I get is the following:

> `SignatureDoesNotMatch`  The request
>   signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
>   Check your key and signing method. 
>   AKKSAJBCJBSbXC3NQ  POST
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded 1567098922
>   /jwplatform-upload/Qsafas6vB 
>   WWbjcskWBKlc/BLxbm6/RJg57u7M=
>    50 4f 53 54 0a 0a 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e
>   2f 31 2d 77 77 77 2d 66 6f 72 6d 2d 75 72 6c 65 6e 64 6f 64 65 64 0a
>   31 35 36 37 30 39 38 39 32 32 0a 2f 6a 77 70 6c 23 74 66 6f 72 6d 2d
>   75 70 6c 6f 61 64 2f 51 72 4e 53 33 36 76 42 
>   8D9AA0A3719CE53F 
>   3x6mnassasaQ2PEFVmc9GZwp0Y7yFS1FtasakDgY39EktjlwX2UsoViikqiE8bDcG6pKB4YPXvsH1Q=

Answer (score 3):

Try with a PUT, not a POST. We have documentation for this at https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/reference/v1/s3_uploads.html#uploading-file

Comment: I have already tried with PUT but it gives me another error:
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>5B0299C0EE8CDCD9</RequestId>
<HostId>
gzXQfQSqHqyEZeucIzGZh9FKyBnn17jtJp0GTYQ38fnytAbTk6CUq+UoPSXeBNHf8HgQNVXyWvc=
</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: This worked for me! I wish this was documented explicitly in new API docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload files in the browser, you should use HTTP **PUT** instead of **POST**, and the `Content-Type` of the request headers **MUST** be a **MIME type** instead of `multipart/form-data`, and the parameters of the API the MIME type **MUST** also be given (both v1 and v2), Finally, you **CANNOT** use `FormData` to make requests. Here is my complete sample code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Button, Upload } from "antd";
import JWPlatformAPI from "jwplatform";

const V1_API_CREDENTIALS_KEY = "<V1_API_Credentials_Key>";
const V1_API_CREDENTIALS_SECRET = "<V1_API_Credentials_Secret>";
const V2_API_CREDENTIALS_SECRET = "<V2_API_Credentials_Secret>";
const SITE_ID = "<SITE_ID>";

const jwApi = new JWPlatformAPI({
  apiKey: V1_API_CREDENTIALS_KEY,
  apiSecret: V1_API_CREDENTIALS_SECRET
});

export default function App() {
  const [uploadUrl, setUploadUrl] = useState(null);

  const createUploadUrlV1 = () => {
    jwApi.videos
      .create({
        upload_method: "s3",
        upload_content_type: "video/mp4"
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const {
          link: {
            protocol,
            address,
            path,
            query: { AWSAccessKeyId, Expires, Signature }
          }
        } = response;
        const encodedSignature = encodeURIComponent(Signature);
        setUploadUrl(
          `${protocol}://${address}${path}?AWSAccessKeyId=${AWSAccessKeyId}&Expires=${Expires}&Signature=${encodedSignature}&api_format=json`
        );
      });
  };
  const createUploadUrlV2 = () => {
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: `https://api.jwplayer.com/v2/sites/${SITE_ID}/media/`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: V2_API_CREDENTIALS_SECRET
      },
      data: {
        upload: {
          method: "direct",
          mime_type: "video/mp4"
        }
      }
    }).then(({ data }) => {
      setUploadUrl(data.upload_link);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={createUploadUrlV1}>
        v1 create S3 direct upload URL
      </button>
      <button onClick={createUploadUrlV2}>
        v2 create S3 direct upload URL
      </button>
      <div>S3 direct upload URL: {uploadUrl}</div>
      <Upload
        action={uploadUrl}
        headers={{
          "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
        }}
        method="PUT"
        name="file"
        customRequest={({
          action,
          file,
          headers,
          onError,
          onProgress,
          onSuccess
        }) => {
          axios
            .put(action, file, {
              headers,
              onUploadProgress: ({ total, loaded }) => {
                onProgress(
                  { percent: Math.round((loaded / total) * 100).toFixed(2) },
                  file
                );
              }
            })
            .then((event) => {
              const { data } = event;
              onSuccess(data, file);
            })
            .catch(onError);
          return {
            abort() {
              console.log("upload progress is aborted.");
            }
          };
        }}
      >
        <Button>Click to Upload</Button>
      </Upload>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I suggest that JWP should update the documentation as soon as possible.